# What is the name of this device for back massage?

Tags: injuries

What is the name of the device?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE! I closed your question because it is [not clear what you are asking](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10937530#10937530) **in the context of sports**. However, I am glad you were able to find an answer.

Comment: The question was so simple as it is in the title. I only added to the body text to meet the requirements about length. It was easy to find answers to the rest of the questions by google. I think it is now enough clear.

Comment: Again, how so in the context of sports? The question is as simple as read, yes, but in what relation does your question have with sports?

Comment: Regression is very important part of sports.

Comment: I see nothing in your question in how you relate regression specific to sports. Do you plan to use this device to help your recovery in a specific sport/exercise/fitness activity? Simply asking to identify the device doesn't scope your question in any of the aforementioned categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thing seems to be an [*Arco Largo*](http://www.bodycodesystem.com/arco-largo/?lang=en). I don't know if it has a generic name.

Comment: Over here its known as a Backstretcher